# Is there an easier way of getting Utc time in gamemaker?

Tags: utc, game-maker

The only way I have found is this:

```
round(date_second_span(date_create_datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0),date_current_datetime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

GM has not special functions for working with UTC time, so you can use scripts for convert. For back convert you can use this, if need:

```
/// date_timestamp(timestamp)
// Convert UNIX time to GMS time

var t = date_inc_second(25569+1, argument0);
return date_inc_day(t, -1);
```

+1 and -1 needed because GMS has a [bug](http://bugs.yoyogames.com/view.php?id=14811)